# How do I convert videos files into a .bik format?

Tags: video-conversion

I'm in need of some advice after several days of doing research on and off has brought me no answers.

I'm self-taught with coding and I want to create a program in C# with Microsoft Visual Studi (2017) that will convert video files ***into .bik videos***. So I can take an mp3, wmv, etc, and turn them *into .bik* video files. The reason I state this, is because when I ask in the past, (here or on other sites) people have pointed me to online programs that convert .bik videos into more common file types.

RAD Tools is not an option, as once it's unzipped, it sets off my antivirus defender and I'm not risking my work computer. I've wanted to do this for a while, and now I'm determined to really knuckle down and do it.

So, with someone who has some experience in Unity game development, with C# as their main language of choice, what's the best way to go about learning video conversion to turn common video files into a .bik format?

Whether it's a tutorial, a scripting library, anything is helpful because there's not much information on this out there.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you won't find anything that isn't on the editor's website, .bik IS a proprietary codec after all. So even if you're not using the complete RAD Tools, you'd at the very least use one file responsible for encoding that they shipped with it.

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/Suprnova/Heavy-Iron-Bik-Converter